# computed property not returning correct value in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue.js project where uses can select an item (an app) from a select input element. It uses an apps array that is specified in the data section. All of that is working correctly.

```
    <div class="large-8 columns" v-if="selectedAppId">
      {{selectedApp.name}}
    </div>
    <div class="large-8 columns" v-else>
      <select v-model="selectedAppId" name="timeline_event[site_id]">
        <option value=null>Select One</option>
        <option v-for="app in apps" :value="app.id" :key="app.id">{{app.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'd like to be able to return the selectedApp from the apps array and output the name as seen in the first part of the conditional above.

I'm not sure if a computed property is the correct way to do this - I have also tried as a method and that was problematic. In the following, the correct app is selected from the apps array but rather than rendering out the `selectedApp.name`, I get an error stating "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

In my console.log, it is outputting an **ob** Observer. I am obviously not doing this correctly. What would be the correct way to do this?

```
  computed: {
    selectedApp(){
      console.log('here is selectedAppId ' + this.selectedAppId)
      this.apps.forEach((app) => {
        if(app.id == this.selectedAppId){
          console.log('a hit');
          console.log(app)
          return app
        }else{
          console.log('a miss');
        }
      })
    },
  },
```

Comment: Did you try use watcher for variable `selectedAppId` ? It looks like it will be the best option for your use case https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property

Comment: thx @CaShiS - I didn't. Let me try that. Still trying to figure out the best way to handle parts of Vue.

Comment: first, change `<option value=null>Select One</option>` to `<option value="" disabled>Select One</option>`, it will prevent from this option is selected then causes `selectedAppId` is null. then `computed: {
    selectedApp(){}` didn't return one value, use `Array.find` is better than `Array.forEach` as below answer of @sovalina at your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need a `forEach` loop but just find the match between your `selectedAppId` (which is fill with the `app.id`) and the `app`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      selectedAppId: '',
      apps: [{ id: 1, name: "App1" }, { id:2,  name: "App2" }, { id: 3,  name: "App3" }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    selectedApp(){
      return this.apps.find(app => app.id == this.selectedAppId )
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="large-8 columns" v-if="selectedAppId">
      {{ selectedApp.name }}
    </div>
    <div class="large-8 columns" v-else>
      <select v-model="selectedAppId" name="timeline_event[site_id]">
        <option value=null>Select One</option>
        <option v-for="app in apps" :value="app.id" :key="app.id">{{app.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
```